# Optimal sorting algorithm in a fpga

Tags: fpga, algorithm

I have a fixed set of 9 values that needs to be sorted in an FPGA.

What would be an optimal sorting algorithm to implement?

Comment: Would requiring 9! comparators be an issue?

Comment: Please define "optimal". Fastest? Smallest? Least power? Easiest to code?

Comment: Optimal = Least number of logical blocks needed.

Comment: How many clock cycles can we use?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: Even if you're comparing every value to every other value, why would you need more than n*(n-1)/2 comparators?

Comment: @DaveTweed Silly me, that's rather a big difference!

Comment: I don't know what a 'logical block' might be, but for this small number I would probably use insertion sort, maybe a heap sort.

Comment: Before we can even start to consider making this "optimal", too much depends on how a "value" is represented (integer? how many bits?) and what the handshake protocol with the outside world is. Please specify. Since you want to minimize the physical size, we will assume that computation time is not an issue at all.

Comment: I'm very interested in this question, because I need to do high-performance sorting in FPGAs all the time (anywhere from 5 to 1024 items), and I've been giving this some thought. Assuming 16-bit data and fairly "generic" 4- or 5-input LUTs, I think I can sort a list of up to 16 items in something on the order of 100 clock cycles and 100-150 LUTs. I'll need to code it up to get a more specific number, but I'm not going to put any effort into an answer unless the OP comes back and clarifies what he wants.

Answer (score 5):

Sorting in an FPGA is typically done using a [Sorting network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network).
One good example of a sorting network is [Bitonic Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sort). A sorting network is a fixed network of comparators where the order of operations does not depend on the data. Bitonic sort has a complexity of O(n*log(n)^2), although it is not O(n*log(n)) like sorting algorithms popularly used in software implementations it is still often more efficient to implement in an FPGA due to its fixed structure.

For small arrays such as your 9-values you can just have a fixed sorting network with a throughput of 9 sorted values per clock cycle. If you have larger arrays or lower throughput requirements the sorting operation can be computed in different passes kind of like an FFT where a fixed k-input bitonic sort network is applied to the data several times. Typically k is chosen large enough to minimize the number of passes while keeping the data-path size feasible. The smallest bitonic sort network is a 2-input network where one output is the minimum value and the other is the maximum value.